# Matrix transformations on objects

Tags: matrices, transformation

I am trying to solve the following question:
[image: question]

I have created the scaling, translation and rotation matrices that I feel will transform the left figure to the figure on the right:

Scaling
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0.5 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Translation
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -5 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Rotation
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -\sqrt{3}/2 & 0.5 & 0 \\
        -0.5 & -\sqrt{3}/2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

However, when I do the matrix multiplication for the matrices I have created, I don't get any of the options listed. The correct answer is supposed to be B. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why are all of these matrices 3 dimensional? And what is a homogeneous matrix?

Comment: @mrstopstraffic Have a look at this link: https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-09-fall/Handouts/handout15.pdf

Comment: Thanks! That is a most helpful handout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer should be given by scaling * rotation * translation. But your rotation matrix is wrong. From the figure, you need to rotate the object by -$\pi/3$, so your rotation matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}0.5 && \sqrt 3 /2&&0\\-\sqrt 3 /2&& 1/2 &&0\\0&&0&&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Why does the object need to be rotated by $-\pi/3$?

Comment: Never mind, I get it. You're supposed to use the angle on the right hand side which works out to be $\pi - \pi/2 - \pi/6$